# Import celery task without importing dependencies

Tags: python, celery

I have two modules

```
alpha.py
beta.py
```

`beta.py` can only be run on `beta.server` because it requires a licensed solver than only exists on `beta.server`.

Within `alpha.py`, there's a portion of code that calls:

```
beta_task.apply_async(kwargs={...})
```

As such, it requires

```
from beta import beta_task
```

Which in turn requires the magical proprietary module that is only available on `beta.server`.

I need to enable `alpha_task` to run on `alpha.server`, having the ability to call `beta_task` without having the `beta_task` code on the server.

Is this possible?

## UPDATE

Also, can I prevent `beta.task` from running on `alpha.server`?

Since `alpha.py` import `beta.py`, the daemon finds `beta.task` and listens for tasks of this type:

```
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app_app
- ** ---------- .> transport:   asdfasdfasd
- ** ---------- .> results:     adfasdfasdf
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

 [tasks]
  . alpha.alpha_task
  . beta.beta_task
```

Comment: Is your beta module located on an NFS file system on alpha.server? You can check this by doing df -T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this before but never got it to work "right". I used a hacky workaround instead.

You can put the `import proprietary` statement in the `beta.beta_task` def itself.  Your 'alpha' file doesn't actually run the 'beta' def, it just uses celery's task decorator to dispatch a message about it.

While PEP standards dictate a module should be at the top on the outermost scope, it's actually common practice for widely used PyPi modules to place the import within a registration or called function so that uninstalled dependencies for the unused files won't break the package [for example, a caching library will import redis/memcached modules within the backend activation, so the 3rd party modules aren't needed unless that backend is used].

alpha.py

```
from beta import beta_task

beta_task.apply_async(kwargs={...})
```

beta.py

```
@task
def beta_task(args):
    import proprietary
    proprietary.foo()
```

For the Update about running different tasks on each server: that is all covered in the "routing" chapter of the celery docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html

You basically configure different 'queues' (one for alpha, one for beta); start the workers to only handle the queues you specify; and either specify the route in the call to apply_async or configure the celery daemon to match a task to a route (there are several ways to do that, all explained in that chapter with examples.)

Comment: I actually tried this out. It solves one of the two problems I encountered (The import portion; I'll update the post to mention the second). Is there a way to start the daemon and have it only activate alpha.task on alpha.server (as opposed to starting alpha.task AND beta.task)

Comment: Yeah, that's covered in the "routing" chapter of the celery docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html  You basically configure different 'queues' (one for alpha, one for beta); start the workers to only handle the queues you specify; and either specify the route in the call to apply_async or configure the celery daemon to match a task to a route (several ways, all in that chapter)

Comment: if you want to be even nastier, you can put a global statement before that import. This way, your whole script can use the variable

Answer (score 21):

I was able to get something like this working in my project by putting each module which needed to be separated in a different project and instantiating a Celery App in each with the same name. I then called the [task by name](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-call-a-task-by-name).

```
# Import the app you created in the celeryconfig.py for your project
from celeryconfig import app

app.send_task('beta.tasks.beta_task', args=[2, 2], kwargs={})
```

I then can run one project on one server and the other on a different server and they are connected via the broker, but do not actually need to import code from each other.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. It just sends a task to Celery without messing around with imports at all. It decouples the producer from the consumer in a much better way.

Comment: Just in case anyone hasn't come across it yet, you can use the optional `name` argument when calling `@task`. So to make this example work, you would need to call `@app.task(name="beta.tasks.beta_task")`.

Comment: This is a lot less hacky solution than the accepted answer indeed.

Comment: Note that when using send_task, most task options you attached to the task from the `@task` decorator will be ignored. You will need to pass these options through `send_task` yourself.

Comment: Will that work with tasks autodiscover (which is started in `celery.py`)?